# PowerShell Azure Storage emulator

Tags: azure, powershell, storage, azure-storage-emulator

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to start all the services I need for my development environment and am struggling to find a way to launch azure storage emulator. All I need is a way to start the service but everything i've read online isn't doing the trick.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi Chris, if the answer works for you, please help mark it as answer.

Comment: This done the trick thanks very much for the help was just having issues with the spacing in the pro files folder but that seems to have done the trick. much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you manually launch the azure storage emulator, you can find this command line: `AzureStorageEmulator.exe start` , screenshot as below:
[image]

so in your powershell script, you can just run this cmd command line:

```
cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start
```

Then the service starts, screenshot as below:
[image]